# Exporting multiple functions in one module in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I ran into a problem in Nodejs(with express) while trying to export a module with two functions which is structured as follows

```
exports.class1 = function(){
    return = {
         method1 : function(arg1, arg2){
             ...........
         },
         method2 : function (arg2, arg3, arg4){
             ..........  
         }

   };

 }
```

this module is saved in as module1.js
when it is imported and used as follows an error occurs

```
var module1 = require('./module1');

module1.class1.method1(arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: what is that an error?

Comment: Why are you exporting a function? Export the object. And your `return` syntax isn't right...

Comment: can you please correct the return syntax

Comment: I added an answer which gives both exporting `function` & `object`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `class1` should have code like bellow

```
exports.class1 = function(){
    return {
         method1 : function(arg1, arg2){
             console.log(arg1,arg2)
         },
         method2 : function (arg2, arg3, arg4){
             console.log(arg2,arg3,arg4);
         }

   };

 }
```

And you have to call it like bellow

```
module1.class1().method1(arg1, arg2);//because class1 is a function
```

A better way to do it to export an object

```
  exports.class1 = {
         method1 : function(arg1, arg2){
             console.log(arg1,arg2)
         },
         method2 : function (arg2, arg3, arg4){
             console.log(arg2,arg3,arg4);
         }
 }
```

And you can call it like

```
module1.class1.method1(arg1, arg2); //because here class1 is an object
```

Comment: When using it as an object is it possible to call method1 within method2??

Comment: @ShenalSilva not in this situation, then you have to do something like this see here  http://pastebin.com/7EYHhai7